# How to write a function that appends a variable number of elements to a lazy list with each iteration?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml

The motivating problem is: Code a lazy list whose elements are all possible combinations of 0 and 1 i.e. [0], [1], [0;0], [0;1], etc..

Working in OCaml, I've written auxiliary functions for generating the list of permutations of length n+1 given n and for converting a list into a lazy list. The problem comes from the final function in the below block of code:

```
type 'a seq =
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq)

let rec adder = function
    | [] -> [] 
    | [[]] -> [[0];[1]]
    | xs::ys -> (0::xs)::(1::xs)::(adder ys)

let rec listtoseq = function
    | [] -> Nil
    | xs::ys -> Cons(xs, fun () -> listtoseq ys)

let rec appendq xq yq =
    match xq with
        | Nil -> yq
        | Cons (x, xf) -> Cons (x, fun() -> appendq (xf ()) yq)

let genlist xs = appendq (listtoseq xs) (genlist (adder xs))
```

Calling genlist [[0];[1]] results in a stack overflow. The issue seems to be that since genlist is an infinite loop I want to delay evaluation, yet evaluation is needed for appendq to work.

If this were a problem where one element is added to the lazy list at a time I could solve it, but I think the difficulty is that each set of length n permutations must be added at a time, and thus I don't know any other solution besides using an append function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at your problem is that `appendq` isn't lazy enough.  You can make things work if you define a function `appendqf` with this type:

```
'a seq -> (unit -> 'a seq) -> 'a seq
```

In other words, the second parameter isn't a sequence. It's a function that returns a sequence.

(Note that this type, `unit -> 'a seq`, is what actually appears inside a `Cons`.)

I tried this and it works for me.